# Conexões Clonadas

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, conexão, clone

Gostaria de saber se existe como criar apenas uma conexão com o banco de dados para execução das tarefas. A cada Action executado, é criada uma conexão com o Banco de Dados e ao final da execução do Action, a conexão é encerrada. Então, quando é necessário executar uma Action dentro de outra ficam duas conexões abertas além da que foi aberta para primeira consulta ao banco de dados, criando, assim, vários clones de conexão.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que resolve isto e como usá-la. Se precisar de algum código para dar um melhor entendimento sobre o que preciso eu posto aqui.

Comment: Você está usando algum framework?

Comment: Uso o framework Yii. E o banco de dados é o PostGresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente se usa o recurso gerado por pg_connect para todas as conexões. Mas vc não necessariamente precisa seguir essa regra. Pode criar uma conexão para cada "action".

Eu faria diferente: ao invés de uma conexão pra cada action eu usaria uma transação por action. Código [aqui](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlphp/trans/).

Usando o Yii, vc não usará diretamente as funções de postgres do PHP, mas a lógica é mesma. Tem [aqui](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html) o jeito de fazer isso com Yii.

Comment: Ok! Obrigada pela resposta. Vou verificar isso!